# "One blue ball and one red ball is" or "are"?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which is correct?

> - One blue ball and one red ball is preferred.
> - One blue ball and one red ball are preferred.

Comment: See [Singular or plural following a list](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/singular-or-plural-following-a-list): where a list is the subject of a verb, use the plural form.

Comment: @Tim: I assume you're thinking along these lines:  'in the Cambridge Grammar are references to what are termed "singular / plural overrides" where the speaker indicates his or her interpretation of the subject as being singular or plural, irrespective of its grammatical status.' (Shoe, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56210/singular-or-plural-verb-form-where-subject-includes-a-parenthetical-element ). So here, perhaps: _for the starting position for the game 'User42 Pool', one blue ball and one red ball is preferred_?

Comment: However, in the alternatives offered in the question, where such overrides are not stated, the answer is clear.

Comment: @TimLymington Whatever you meant!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Obviously, the OP did not mean a situation as extrapolated. Imagination does run wild! :)

Answer (score -1):

"One blue ball and one red ball are preferred."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We normally prefer reasons or citations in an answer; otherwise it is just one person's opinion, which is not very helpful.