# The mayor as well as his brothers is/are going to prison

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

Which of these is correct?

> The mayor as well as his brothers is going to prison.
>
> The mayor as well as his brothers are going to prison.

Comment: "The mayor and his brothers are going to prison."

Comment: Singular or plural verb form where subject includes a “parenthetical” element: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56210/singular-or-plural-verb-form-where-subject-includes-a-parenthetical-element

Comment: @HotLicks That's **not** the question!

Comment: @Kris - But it's the answer.

Comment: You can either do "The mayor, as well as his brothers, is going to prison" or "The mayor as well as his brothers are going to prison."

Answer (score 0):

As well as has a similar meaning to "not only but also" equivalent to : not only the mayor is going to prison but also his father.

In other words it means in addition to.

You can also say:

The mayor, as well as his brother, is going to prison.

When it is used as "an addition" operator, as well as does not change the number of the subject.

Answer (score -1):

"Is", it's the mayor that is going to prison

Comment: Should it not be "are"? If you take "as well as" to mean "and", then you form a compound subject. The verb (to go) then has to use the plural agreement. (The mayor and his brothers = they, hence "they are going".)

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). Maybe an explanation would help the OP resolve such questions him/herself in the future and it would be more helpful for other users. Can you please edit and explain a little?

Comment: @WindowsDude7 it does not mean and it means in "addition to",that's why it does not take the number of the subject

Comment: @Eddinho Thank you for the clarification. I wasn't 100% sure of the meaning of "as well as" so I took my best guess.