# Two days "is" or "are"?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, measuring-units

I have heard about the usage of "be" in specific situations like **2 days**, **5 dollars**,... 
For example:

> Two days ____ enough for us

Should I use "is" or "are"? I see both of them are appropriate.

Comment: *Is* if you're treating the two days as a single length of time; *are* if you're treating them as multiple lengths of time.

Comment: @Lawrence I know that, but what do you think is more appropriate?

Comment: It depends - are you treating "two days" as a single length of time, or as multiple lengths of time?

Comment: So both of them can be both correct answers, right?

Comment: Whether either or both are "correct" depends on the context. Both are grammatically sound, though.

Comment: Possibly of interest: [Singular verb after two noun phrases joined by “and” that can be thought of as a single thing](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/97461/142322), and [Singular or plural verb form where subject includes a “parenthetical” element](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56210/singular-or-plural-verb-form-where-subject-includes-a-parenthetical-element).

Comment: Look at the five units case with 'five cents'. 'Five cents is not much to pay for a bag' would never be used with plural agreement. But 'Five cents are lying in a pile on the table' needs the plural verb-form. // This is a multi-dupicate, but I'll close-vote for lack of research.

Comment: Please include the research you've done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references (eg already on ELU) are off-topic.